# How to clear all initialized (with code) label classes in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

My code loops through all the files in a folder then makes a label for them. Before it does though, you need to open the folder using `FolderBrowserDialog`. I want to make it so: When there's a folder **ALREADY** open in the program, I can clear all of those labels so there's room for the new batch of labels.
Code:

````cs
foreach(string song in files)
                {
                    

                    Label songLab = new Label();
                    songLab.Padding = new Padding(6);
                    songLab.AutoSize = true;
                    
                    songLab.Location = new Point(prevX + 10, prevY + 20);
                    songLab.Click += (o, e2) =>
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("You Clicked " + songLab.Text);
                    };
                    songLab.MouseEnter += (o, e3) =>
                    {
                        Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
                        songLab.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    };
                    
                    songLab.MouseLeave += (o, e4) =>
                    {
                        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                        songLab.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    };
                    
                    Controls.Add(songLab);
                    
                    int fileExtPos = song.LastIndexOf(".");
                    var songFixd = song.Substring(0, fileExtPos);
                    
                    
                    prevY += 20;
                    songLab.Text += songFixd + "\n";
                }
    ```
````

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to keep a separate list of labels:

```
myLabels.Add(songLab);
Controls.Add(songLab);
```

Then you can loop thru it and delete the labels:

```
foreach(var label in myLabels){
    Controls.Remove(label);
}
```

However, it sounds like you are doing something like a [listview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/listview-control-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) or [datagrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/datagrid-control-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). Using these might be better than adding labels manually. You could also consider a fully custom control where you manage all the drawing and event-handling yourself rather than relying on existing controls.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! I really appreciate it.
As to the last suggestion, I'm really a beginner... That's why it's pretty hard for me.

Comment: @Jack Rivera , If you are new, there is more reasons to use existing controls rather than trying to hack together something.

Comment: Well yes, I'm pretty new. I just like making some projects in Winforms and I think it's very cool.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use `groupbox` (or a control like that). Add the Labels to the `groupbox` like this:

```
groupBox1.Controls.Add(songLab);
```

And delete from `groupbox` when deleting in bulk like this:

```
groupBox1.Controls.Clear();
```